# Сортировка элементов List с помощью компаратора

Tags: c#, сортировка

Наткнулся на такой метод:

```
public void SortByName()
{
   studentList.Sort((b1, b2) => string.Compare(b1.Name, b2.Name));   
}
```

К сожалению, я не смог найти более менее понятного мне объяснения на MSDN, поэтому прошу вашей помощи. Как я понимаю, метод Sort не должен принимать параметры, но здесь в качестве параметра передано лямбда выражение.

Comment: Уважаемые редакторы вопроса, вы уж пожалуйста определитесь с дополнительными метками для вопроса, а то один убирает, другой добавляет, а под вопросом ни одного комментария.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У класса `List<T>` есть [несколько методов `Sort`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1). Один из них [без параметров](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort), другой [принимает на вход делегат](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) `Comparison<T>` для сравнения элементов массива. В вашем коде вызывается именно второй.

Сигнатура делегата `Comparison<T>` —

```
int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y)
```

То есть ваша лямбда-функция подходит, т. к. метод `string.Compare` возвращает `int`.

---

Остальные две перегрузки метода `Sort` принимают для сравнения интерфейс `ICompaere<T>`, а также диапазон индексов на случай, если отсортировать нужно лишь часть списка.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
var result = students.OrderBy(student =>student.Name).ThenBy(student => student.Age).ToArray();
```

Сделал еще один пример. С помощью Linq возможно будет понятее.

У List есть методы расширение от интерфейса IEnumerable, OrderBy метод принимает в себя делегат и соритирует по указанному полю "student =>student.Name". Что бы указать дополнительное поле в случае, если Name равны используется метод ThenBy.